# ESP8266-12e help

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266

Having tons of issues with my first attempts at using this board. I have a lot of experience using arduino's and various microcontrollers, but my current project requires WiFi connectivity. I ordered the esp-12 and have had trouble getting it to be stable at all. I'm using the arduino IDE.

No matter what sketch I use, even if it just a loop printing to serial, it is unbelievably unstable. It will print fine for a while, then non stop exception errors and stack traces. The exception numbers vary each time, usually 0/29/8. It's just super intermittent. It will work fine for 20 minutes and then just spam errors until I reset and re upload my sketch. I notice that it occurs almost every time I reset the board. I started using it just as it came without flashing any new firmware. I thought that it could be the issue, but then I flashed the lasted nodemcu, and there was no change.

I assume it is something with my power setup, since it seems like they are very sensitive, but I think I am doing it right. I'm using this schematic for the board:
esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/ESP_improved_stability.png

A CP2102 Serial cable is used to interface with the board

Voltage is regulated with a LD1117V33 voltage regulator, from a 2AMP 5V wall power supply.

I connect the serial cable's 3.3v power to my common power rail, because it doesn't upload without that (I feel like this may be my issue).

I'm really bad at drawing schematics, so here's a picture of my voltage regulator board and the esp board. To upload I bring GPIO0 to low and have reset low and as it starts to upload bring it high. Thanks a lot for any help.

[image: Board wiring]

[image: Voltage Regulator]

Comment: you picked the most finicky ESP-way to expand; don't get burned out on ESPs as a result; nodeMCUs are MUCH easier to get working. Your support hardware itself sounds fine. several questions: 1. how do you even fit those weird-spaced pins in a breadboard? 2. are you running ardunio or nodemcu? 3. where's the little flat capacitors? 4. don't connect the 3.3 of the serial, connect the ground. 5. make sure RST, CHPD, and GPIOs 0+1+15 are pulled right.

Comment: @dandavis Yeah I know it seems finicky, but I need to eventually transfer to a pcb for a production product, so I don't have much of a choice unfortunately. 1. I used single strand solid wire to extend and just spread them out a bit. 2. I flashed it with nodemcu, and am using arduino IDE to program. 3. Not sure what you mean? I'm using several of the cylindrical black capacitors. 4. OK that's what I was thinking, though it seems to run more unstable with that source removed. 5. I have, though there is so much conflicting info online about which pins need to be pulled up/down.  Thank you

Comment: I don't have a clear answer, because any number of things might be going wrong with your breadboard design, but I would advise buying a NodeMCU or Wemos development board (they're stupid cheap, ~3USD or less) and develop on that. It will make your life much easier, and when you transfer to a PCB, you can base your design off the NodeMCU design (I have done this and had no issues).

Comment: @dandavis That's probably a good idea. But when transferring to the final PCB, what schematic for power and pull up/downs did you use? Since yeah I can dev on the NodeMCU, but I still need a final solution for using the esp-12e

Comment: basically the nodemcu devkit w/o the reset and analog stuff.